# Sequelize not retrieving all data after insert

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have noticed that my backend is not retrieving the expected data after an insert.
In my React application, I have one function which inserts data into the database and after getting a response, a new request is sent to update the current component state with the newly fetched data.
All my functions are using await/async and in the backend, all transactions are correctly used and committed in order.

My client is calling the following endpoints:
-POST: api/ticket ( INSERT AN ITEM)
-GET: api/ticket (GET ALL ITEMS)

Here is what the backend is showing which looks correct to me, the problem is that in the 'SELECT' statement, the inserted item is not retrieved.
The transactions are started from two different routes but I don't see why it should be an issue.
In addition, I tried to change the AddItem function to output the same findAll statement which is called when using the GET method and the data returned are correct.
So why if I separate these two flows I do not get all the items? I always need to refresh the page to get the added item.

```
START TRANSACTION;
Executing (a9d14d5c-c0ac-4821-9b88-293b086debaa): INSERT INTO `messages` (`id`,`message`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`ticketId`,`userId`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?);
Executing (a9d14d5c-c0ac-4821-9b88-293b086debaa): COMMIT;
Executing (9ee9ddaa-294e-41d1-9e03-9f02a2737030): START TRANSACTION;
Executing (9ee9ddaa-294e-41d1-9e03-9f02a2737030): SELECT `ticket`.`id`, `ticket`.`subject`, `ticket`.`status`, `ticket`.`createdAt`, `ticket`.`updatedAt`, `ticket`.`deletedAt`, `ticket`.`userId`, `messages`.`id` AS `messages.id`, `messages`.`message` AS `messages.message`, `messages`.`sender` AS `messages.sender`, `messages`.`createdAt` AS `messages.createdAt`, `messages`.`updatedAt` AS `messages.updatedAt`, `messages`.`deletedAt` AS `messages.deletedAt`, `messages`.`ticketId` AS `messages.ticketId`, `messages`.`userId` AS `messages.userId`, `messages->user`.`id` AS `messages.user.id`, `messages->user`.`firstname` AS `messages.user.firstname`, `messages->user`.`surname` AS `messages.user.surname`, `messages->user`.`email` AS `messages.user.email`, `messages->user`.`password` AS `messages.user.password`, `messages->user`.`stripeId` AS `messages.user.stripeId`, `messages->user`.`token` AS `messages.user.token`, `messages->user`.`birthDate` AS `messages.user.birthDate`, `messages->user`.`status` AS `messages.user.status`, `messages->user`.`confirmationCode` AS `messages.user.confirmationCode`, `messages->user`.`createdAt` AS `messages.user.createdAt`, `messages->user`.`updatedAt` AS `messages.user.updatedAt`, `messages->user`.`deletedAt` AS `messages.user.deletedAt` FROM `tickets` AS `ticket` LEFT OUTER JOIN `messages` AS `messages` ON `ticket`.`id` = `messages`.`ticketId` AND (`messages`.`deletedAt` IS NULL) LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` AS `messages->user` ON `messages`.`userId` = `messages->user`.`id` AND (`messages->user`.`deletedAt` IS NULL) WHERE (`ticket`.`deletedAt` IS NULL);
Executing (9ee9ddaa-294e-41d1-9e03-9f02a2737030): COMMIT;
```

-- POST '/api/ticket

```
exports.addMessage = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await sequelize.transaction(async (t) => {
      var ticketId = req.body.ticketId;
      const userId = req.body.userId;
      const message = req.body.message;
      const subject = req.body.subject;

      // Validate input - If new ticket, a subject must be provided
      if (!ticketId && !subject) {
        return res
          .status(400)
          .send({ message: "New ticket must have a subject" });
      }
      // Validate input - If ticket exists, userId and message must be provided
      if (!userId && !message && ticketId) {
        return res
          .status(400)
          .send({ message: "UserID and message are required" });
      }
      // Create ticket is no ticketID was provided
      if (!ticketId) {
        const [ticket, created] = await Ticket.findOrCreate({
          where: {
            subject: subject,
            userId: userId,
          },
          transaction: t,
        });
        ticketId = ticket.id;
      }
      // Create a new message object
      const messageObject = await db.message.create(
        {
          message: message,
          userId: userId,
          ticketId: ticketId,
        },
        { transaction: t }
      );
      // Output message object
      return res.send(messageObject);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(500).send({
      message:
        err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the ticket message.",
    });
  }
};
```

-- GET: api/ticket

```
exports.findAll = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await sequelize.transaction(async (t) => {
      const tickets = await db.ticket.findAll(
        {
          include: [{ model: db.message, include: [db.user] }],
        },
        { transaction: t }
      );
      tickets.forEach((ticket) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(ticket.messages.length));
      });

      return res.send(tickets);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send({
      message: err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving Tickets.",
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you show both Sequelize queries and input for the first one

Comment: The question was updated with the relevant code from the backend.  In the first place, the addMessage function was decomposed into several child functions. I recently merged all of them into one to see where the error was.

Comment: I have the same issue in another endpoint too, the data is correctly inserted into the database but I don't get the correct result if I call the findAll method from a different request right after the POST one. It works only if, in the POST request I output the findAll method, but getting data from a post request is not what I want.

Comment: In another scenario, I noticed that, if updating the item without creating a new instance of it, the findAll() method returns the correct data (updated). Is this issue related to backend performance?

Comment: Additional comment which could help, in my schema definition, all tables have the attribute paranoid set to true. This should impact only when deleting items but maybe there is a background process that somehow doesn't allow the findAll to see the added item?

Comment: Ok, Did you try to execute SQL query to check the actual records in DB right after the POST request has finished?

Comment: I tried and I see in the database, the data is saved because as soon as I refresh the page the data are fetched once more, and the newly added item is there.  Also, if I only update the item I can see that findAll() is returning the items updated

Comment: For the moment, within the post method, I am returning the findAll() result, and in that way, it works by changing the component status with the response data. I'm not sure why the same data is not retrieved when calling the GET method right after the POST one.

Comment: The difference could be only if you call GET before the POST actually finished.

Comment: I noticed you call ` return res.send(messageObject);` inside the transaction and that could be the thing. Move this call right after `sequelize.transaction` call

Comment: @Anatoly Exactly, I had a similar issue before but from the logs I can clearly see that the select query is called right after the insert commit.

Comment: @Anatoly  Many thanks! It did actually work, can you please give me more details in a separate answer? From the logs I don't see any difference at all, so what's the logic of isolating the transaction from the action of responding to the request?

Answer (score 1):

You sent a response to a client **before** the transaction actually was committed.   You just need to move `res.send(messageObject);` outside the transaction call.
You can try to look what's going on in the current version of your code if you add several `console.log` with messages to see what the actual order of actions is (I mean a couple of messages in POST (the last statement inside transaction and after transaction before `res.send`) and at least one at the beginning of GET).

Actually if the transaction was rolled back you'd send an uncommited and already removed object/record that I suppose is not your goal.